Fancyhdr package is only working every other page, but without it page numbers don’t show up on even pages
I am currently writing a report for a final project, with a team. Followed the thesis videos to create a proper report, so there are two folders: one for images and one for ‘chapters’. I am having issues with the page numbering specifically.

With fancyhdr package: numbers every page but package only works on odd pages.

Without fancyhdr package: number are every other page, and blank for even pages.


Here is the current code:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %For inputing images
\graphicspath{{images/}} %bringing in pics from folder
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

%Formatting stuff
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{[Project Name] Design Basis}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\thepage} %Specifies page number location
\fancyfoot[LO,LE]{Section \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Trail Blazers}



%gGets rid of Chapter #... and adding number infront of chapter title
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{ }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}



\title{
    {Design Basis}\\
    {\large University of Colorado Boulder}
}
\author{Team 40 - Trail Blazers}
\date{Month Day, 202X}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{General Information}
    \input{Chapters/1GeneralInformation}

    \chapter{Codes and Standards}
    \input{Chapters/2CodesandStandards}

    \chapter{Units of Measurement}
    \input{Chapters/3UnitsofMeasurement}
    
    \chapter{Site Information}
    \input{Chapters/4SiteInformation}

    \chapter{Plant Design}
    \input{Chapters/5PlantDesign}
        
    \chapter{Battery Limits}
    \input{Chapters/6BatteryLimits}

    \chapter{Engineering Philosophy}
    \input{Chapters/7EngineeringPhilosophy}

    \chapter{Process Operation and Safety}
    \input{Chapters/8ProcessingOperationandSafety}

   \chapter{Raw Material and Product Specifications}
   \input{Chapters/9RawMaterialandProductSpecs}

   \chapter{Process Description and Equipment Basis}
   \input{Chapters/10ProcessDescriptionandEquiptmentBasis}
        
   \chapter{Process Auxiliary Materials}
   \input{Chapters/11ProcessAuxiliaryMaterials}
    
    \chapter{Process Control}
    \input{Chapters/12ProcessControl}

    \chapter{Inventory Basis}
    \input{Chapters/13InventoryBasis}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.  What do you mean by the package only working on odd pages?  How many pages are your chapters?  We don't have your chapters to input - can you remove the input, and just use lipsum to create some content?

@Teepeemm oops. apologies. don't know how I missed that.

what do you mean by "but package only works on odd pages." do you get an error? Please provide an example that shows your problem no one can use the code shown so far replace the files such as  \input{Chapters/2CodesandStandards by some text: enough to show your issue.

you are specifying two side but then specifying the same layout for odd and even, so effectively one side. \fancyfoot[RE,RO]\thepage}  don't you want the page numbers on the outer edge so \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{ ??


It isn't clear what your problem was and you provided no example, but I will attempt an answer.
You were specifying the same format on odd and even pages which makes it hard to see the twoside layout, here I use the normal convention of having page numbers on the outer edge. Also chapter opening use the plain page style which you had not redefined, I added \fancypagestyle{plain}{} so plain page style is the same as the fancy style used on other pages.  I also added \Huge just so the page numbers show in the above image in this test example.
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
% not needed in current latex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %For inputing images
\graphicspath{{images/}} %bringing in pics from folder
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\setlength\headheight{15pt}

%Formatting stuff
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{[Project Name] Design Basis}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\Huge\thepage} %Specifies page number location
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\Huge Section \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{Trail Blazers}



%gGets rid of Chapter #... and adding number infront of chapter title
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter{ }}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}



\title{
    {Design Basis}\\
    {\large University of Colorado Boulder}
}
\author{Team 40 - Trail Blazers}
\date{Month Day, 202X}

\def\aaa{\stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi} red yellow blue green white black}
\def\bbb{\aaa, \aaa\ \aaa\ one two three four five six}
\def\ccc{\bbb. \aaa\ \bbb, \bbb, \bbb, \bbb}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{General Information}
    \ccc, \aaa, \ccc

    \chapter{Units of Measurement}
    \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc.
    \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc.
    \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc, \ccc.
    


\end{document}


Hello, thanks for the help! I apologize for not being clearer in my post, but the code you gave me fixed the issue. Thank you again, I will be more specific with my posts in the future!
